# Row ordering for polygons

Tags: r

My question is simple.  Is there an automatic way to order you data so that it makes "clean" polygons?  I have functions that are generating rings (specifically the ahull function), and I would like a way to cleanly produce polygons using such functions.  Here is an example.

```
x <- c(1:3, 3:1, 1)
y <- c(1,1,1,3,3,2, 1)
xy <- cbind(x,y)

Sr1 <- Polygon(xy)
Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1)) 
plot(SpP) 

z <- runif(7)
xyz <- cbind(x,y,z)
xyz <- xyz[order(z),]

xy <- xyz[,-3]
xy <- rbind(xy, xy[1,])

Sr1 <- Polygon(xy)
Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1)) 
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1)) 
plot(SpP)
```

Here is my real data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8QG4cbDqH0UOUlobnlWaDgwOWs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not sure there is any simple algorithm to "figure out" how to order your vertices so as to avoid having any polygon edges cross each other.  Have you dug thru packages like `spatstat` to see if they have any relevant tools? I know it has tests like `crossing.psp` but I'd hate to have to exhaustively test all segment pairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a sense, you have answered your own question.

Assuming you have a set of points, and you use `ahull(...)` in the `alphahull` package to generate the convex hull, you can extract the points on the boundary, in the correct order, directly from the `ahull` object. Here is an example:

```
library(sp)
library(alphahull)
set.seed(1)            # for reproducible example
X <- rnorm(100)
Y <- rnorm(100)
plot(X,Y)
XY <- cbind(X,Y)
hull <- ahull(XY,alpha=1)
plot(hull)

# extract the row numbers of the boundary points, in convex order.
indx=hull$arcs[,"end1"]  
points <- XY[indx,]                  # extract the boundary points from XY
points <- rbind(points,points[1,])   # add the closing point
# create the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(points)),ID="s1"))) 
plot(SpP)
points(XY)
```

[image]

**EDIT** Response to OP's providing their dataset.

`ahull(...)` seems to fail, without warning, with your dataset - it does not produce any convex hulls. After a bit if experimentation, it looks like the problem has to do with the magnitude of the x,y values. If I divide everything by 1000, it works. No idea what's going one with that (perhaps someone else will provide an insight??). Anyway, here's the code and the result:

```
library(sp)
library(alphahull)
df <- read.csv("ahull problem.csv")
hull <- ahull(df[2:3]/1000,alpha=2)
plot(hull)
# extract the row numbers of the boundary points, in convex order.
indx=hull$arcs[,"end1"]  
points <- df[indx,2:3]               # extract the boundary points from df
points <- rbind(points,points[1,])   # add the closing point
# create the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(points)),ID="s1"))) 
plot(SpP)
points(df[2:3])
```

[image]

Note also that `alpha=2`. Setting `alpha=1` with this dataset actually generates 2 hulls, one with 1 point and one with all the other points. Setting `alpha=2` creates 1 hull.

Comment: Nice solution.  I was under the possible misapprehension that he wanted a polygon which used *all* of his vertices, not just the bounding set. Let's see what the OP comes back with.

Comment: I agree.  Nice solution.  And it should work. But with my real data, it doesn't.  This makes me think that I am missing something basic here (I am new to spatial modeling).  Should the data be ordered in some particular way before going into the ahull function?

Comment: Upload your real data somewhere and post a link in your question.

Comment: Yes, a funny/annoying problem!  If I use alpha = 1200, the plot(hull) works fine, but something happens with the ordering of the rows so that the plot(SpP) ends up producing a polygon with many intersections.

Comment: If I run the code above, replacing `alpha=2` with `alpha=1200`, the SpatialPolygonDataFrame is fine. It is coarser, in the sense that it does not hug the data as closely, but there are no crossings.